# React Quill window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-quill

I added `React Quill` to `Next.js` project and it works fine. But the problem begins when I try to add `ImageResize` to editor.

When I add line

```
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize)
```

I get an error

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

I think the problem is with `Quill` import, but can't find any working solution.

TesxtEditor.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'
import styles from '../styles/Components/TextEditor.module.scss'
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module-react'
import { Quill } from 'react-quill'
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false })

Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize)

interface TextEditorParams {
  onChange: (value: string) => string | void
  placeholder?: string
  error?: boolean
  defaultValue?: string | undefined
  required?: boolean
}

const TextEditor = ({
  onChange,
  placeholder,
  error,
  defaultValue,
  required
}: TextEditorParams) => {
  const [errorState, setErrorState] = useState<boolean | undefined>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    let shouldUpdate = true
    if (shouldUpdate) {
      setErrorState(error)
    }

    return () => {
      shouldUpdate = false
    }
  }, [error])

  const modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
        [{ align: [] }],
        ['link', 'image'],
        ['clean']
      ]
    },
    imageResize: {
      parchment: Quill.import('parchment'),
      modules: ['Resize', 'DisplaySize', 'Toolbar']
    }
  }

  const changeValue = (value: string) => {
    onChange(value)
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.editor}>
      <ReactQuill
        modules={modules}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onChange={(value) => changeValue(value)}
        placeholder={`${placeholder} ${required ? '*' : ''}`}
        className={errorState ? 'textEditor__error' : 'textEditor'}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TextEditor
```

Comment: you have to protect this import against run on serwer. (it running on nextjs ssr part). You can use dynamic import or render this componet (text editior) in component rendererd only on clinet. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr

Comment: I didn't think about use of dynamic to import my `TextEditor` component. This solved my problem. But I didn't like that I have to use dynamic import every time I want to use this component, maybe  there is more delicate solution to do that inside component?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your component in this hellper component.

> **To dynamically load a component on the client side, you can use the ssr option to disable** server-rendering. This is useful if an external dependency or component relies on browser APIs **like window.**

[docs no ssr import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

```js
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const NoSSR = ({ children }) => (
  <>{children}</>
);

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSSR), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Just like that:

```js
import NoSSR from "NoSSR"
import {TextEdior as TextEditortQuill} from "./TextEditor"


const TextEditor = ({...props}) => {

   return (
     <NoSSR>
       <TextEditortQuill {...props}>
     </NoSSR>
   )
}

export default TextEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `react-quill` (v2.0.0) with `quill-image-resize-module-react` (v3.0.0) on nextjs & I faced the same problem....

1. First I found out that I need to `dynamic import` React-Quill or its parent component because this package depends on client side object like window. So here's what I did to import my Editor component which includes react-quill -

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Editor = dynamic(import('components/Editor'), { ssr: false })
```

2. The image resizing worked well until I clicked on any image & pressed `DEL` or `BACKSPACE`, at which point I found this `window.Quill is undefined` error. All I did was add `window.Quill = Quill` to my code & it was good to go again.

```js
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module-react'
import ReactQuill, { Quill } from 'react-quill'
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

window.Quill = Quill
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize)
```

Hope this helps someone save some time debugging

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this problem, you can dynamically load next.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Editor = dynamic(() => import('src/components/editor'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => (
    <Skeleton
      variant="rounded"
      sx={{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        height: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
      }}
    />
  ),
});
```